# Is Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) considered middleware?

Tags: architecture, google-cloud-messaging, middleware

If not middleware, what is the correct architectural term for it?

GCM website: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By definition:

> [Middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) is a computer
>   software that provides services to software applications beyond those
>   available from the operating system. It acts as a bridge between an operating system or database and applications, especially on a network.

For this instance, GCM acts like a [bridge between servers and client apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) (Android/iOS OS).
So to me, it's safe to call it a middleware.